# Identificar repetições de dados no array, e agrupar em um novo array

Tags: php, array-multidimensional, symfony-2, twig

Olá!
Preciso criar um dropdwon usando estilo bootstrap5, onde que, caso o índice "name" de um json conter "/"(barras/slash), significa que cada valor que antecede as barras é um submenu desse dropdown.

Como exemplo de retorno da API, armazenado numa variável do tipo array, segue o seguinte:

```
"result": [
            {
                "scriptid": "11",
                "name": "Config cache reload",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "3",
                "name": "Detect operating system",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "1",
                "name": "Ping",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "7",
                "name": "Telnet",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "2",
                "name": "Traceroute",
           },
            {
                "scriptid": "19",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Disk Free",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "16",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Disk Inodes",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "22",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Java Proccess",
           },
            {
                "scriptid": "21",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Oracle: pmon",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "17",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/ip address",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "14",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/ntpdate query only",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "20",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Windows/AD Groups",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "9",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Proxy/Show IP",
           },
            {
                "scriptid": "6",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Proxy/config_cache_reload",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "8",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/config_cache_reload",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "13",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/housekeeper_execute",
            },
            {
                "scriptid": "18",
                "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/version",
            }
        ],
```

Um detalhe é que em determinado momento, haverá índices repetidos como é o caso do "Zabbix Tools/Linux" ou "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server". Neste caso eu preciso arranjar uma forma de agrupar esses indices, fazendo com que seja inserido o valor correspondente depois desses repetidos, por exemplo:

```
$arrayNovo = [
        0 => [
            "name" => [
                "Zabbix Tools" => [
                    "Zabbix Server" => [
                        0 => [
                            'name' => 'housekeeper_execute',
                            'scriptid' => 13
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'name' => 'version',
                            'scriptid' => 18
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        1 => [
            "name" => [
                "Zabbix Tools" => [
                    "Zabbix Proxy" => [
                        0 => [
                            'name' => 'Show IP',
                            'scriptid' => 9
                        ],
                        1 => [
                            'name' => 'config_cache_reload',
                            'scriptid' => 6
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ];
```

Acredito que com o array neste formato, vai ficar mais fácil montar a eestrutura twig para criar o dropdown.
Bom, caso ficar alguma coisa desentendida, estou a disposição para debater este assunto aqui, no mais, muito grato pela atenção.

Comment: Algum motivo em especial de ficar mesclando array numérico com array associativo? O primeiro e último níveis são numéricos, enquanto os intermediários são associativos. Não funcionaria se fosse tudo associativo?

Comment: @Woss Primeiramente grato pela visualização. Sim, o resultado da tratativa deve ser um array associativo. Consegui um resultado aqui, logo mais vou postar a solução encontrada.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, com a ajuda de um colega de trabalho, conseguimos trazer uma solução para este desafio. Estou levando em conta somente o tratamento para agrupar as informações vindas da API que se repetem em alguns momentos. Após essa iteração terminar, incluo o resultado num arquivo twig usando o método renderView da classe AbstractController. Se alguém se interessar em saber mais detalhes entre em contato comigo.

```
$scripts = json_decode('[
        {
            "scriptid": "11",
            "name": "Config cache reload",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "3",
            "name": "Detect operating system",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "1",
            "name": "Ping",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "7",
            "name": "Telnet",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "2",
            "name": "Traceroute",
       },
        {
            "scriptid": "19",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Disk Free",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "16",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Disk Inodes",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "22",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Java Proccess",
       },
        {
            "scriptid": "21",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/Oracle: pmon",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "17",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/ip address",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "14",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Linux/ntpdate query only",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "20",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Windows/AD Groups",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "9",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Proxy/Show IP",
       },
        {
            "scriptid": "6",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Proxy/config_cache_reload",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "8",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/config_cache_reload",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "13",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/housekeeper_execute",
        },
        {
            "scriptid": "18",
            "name": "Zabbix Tools/Zabbix Server/version",
        }
    ]', true);      
$groupedScripts = [];
    
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    $groupedScripts = $this->parseScript($groupedScripts, $script);
}

private function parseScript(Array $groupedScripts, Array $script): array {
    $scriptid       = $script['scriptid'];
    $name           = $script['name'];
    $separator      = strpos($name, '/');

    if ($separator === false) {
        $groupedScripts[$name] = $scriptid;
    } else {
        $scriptName                     = substr($name, 0, $separator);
        $child                          = $groupedScripts[$scriptName] ?? [];
        $remainingName                  = substr($name, $separator + 1);
        $groupedScripts[$scriptName]    = $this->parseScript($child, ['name' => $remainingName, 'scriptid' => $scriptid]);
    }

    return $groupedScripts;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).